# how do I catch a keyboard event in a mayavi animation

Tags: python, enthought, mayavi

I am looking for a way to catch keyboard events in order to cycle through different datasets in a mayavi animation.

My basic loop is:

```
while 1:
    time = TIME() - zero
    wx.Yield()
    atomsanim[:,:3] = atoms[:,3:]*cos(speed*time) + atoms[:,:3]
    f.scene.disable_render = True
    atom_index = 0
    for t, p in zip(types, plots):
        ms = p.mlab_source
        start = atom_index
        stop = atom_index+t
        ms.set(x=atomsanim[start:stop,0],y=atomsanim[start:stop,1],z=atomsanim[start:stop,2])
        atom_index += t
    f.scene.disable_render = False

mlab.show()
```

Comment: Mayavi has very natural support for mouse picks but not for keyboard events. If you really need keyboard events you should look at adding a `UserInteractorStyle`.  The source code for this is in `tvtk/tvtk_classes.zip/interactor_style_user.py`.

Answer (score 4):

After googling around I found this page: http://osdir.com/ml/python-enthought-devel/2009-01/msg00325.html

Which pretty much solved the problem for me

```
scene.interactor.add_observer('KeyPressEvent', your_function); 
def your_function(vtk_obj, event): 

... and then play with vtk_obj.GetKeyCode()
```